# Android passing variable

Tags: android, variables

I want to pass the content of an edittext to a notification in another .java file. The main part of the code is as follows:

```
   public class HelloAndroid2 extends Activity {  

private Button b2;
public Editable etext;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);   

    EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
    editText.setText("name");
    etext = editText.getText();

    b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button02);
    b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
      //Toast.makeText(HelloAndroid2.this, editText.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast.makeText(HelloAndroid2.this, etext, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
    });

}
```

}

This should be code for calling the etext variable in my MyService.java file: String MyNotifiyText = etext;
What should i do, or how should i call the etext variable in the other .java file?

Answer (score 1):

You can either use a static variable across the two activities or if MyService is calling HelloAndroid2 you can pass the data using intent with extras.

Comment: "You can either use a static variable across the two activities" - how to do this?

Comment: In one of your activities you can keep a static variable , or better yet keep the model class like Heitara suggested

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to create a model class, which will holds all data.

e.g.:

```
package com.examples;

public class DataModel {

    public static String txt = "";

}
```

Yo should put your data in this variable as follows:

```
DataModel.txt = "you string"; //editText.getText();
```

And you can access it from any where:

```
editText.setText(DataModel.txt);
```

Comment: public class DataModel {
     public static String etext;
}
 
There's a problem with this, i have to make it final.
After it is   public static final String etext;, it says "The blank final field etext may not have been initialized"

In the code DataModel.etext = editText.getText(); is also wrong, i have to make etext Editable

So now its declared as  public static final Editable etext, but still the same problem. Now i have to remove the final from the declaration.
If its just public Editable etext;, i have to make it static...then final....so wherever i correct a mistake, another comes up.

Comment: You shouldn't make it final otherwise you can initialize only once. Final is something like a constant, it is initialized only once and can't be changed in future.